# How do I write conditional formatting for banded rows only if the rows are empty?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting

I have followed the tutorials online for conditional formatting of banded rows with the =MOD function. It was a success, and now all even-numbered rows have a background fill. However, the whole column is banded now, and I would only like the formatting to apply when there are values inside those rows. I would like the formatting to continue when I put more values, but I do not want the whole column to be formatted ad infinitum even where there's nothing there. Thank you.

Comment: If you share the exact formula you use, and a screenshot maybe, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just the `=Mod` function, you might use:

```
=AND(Mod(...);NOT(ISBLANK(...)))
```

... for the conditional formatting definition.
The `IsBlank()` worksheet function checks if anything is filled in in the cell.